# Issue with loading system after RAM upgrade

Tags: boot, 20.04, startup, ram

I was trying to upgrade RAM for my Acer Swift 3 laptop(Ubuntu 20.04). It has 8 gb RAM(2 - 4gb sticks) which is expandable up to 12 gb. So, I added 8 gb stick with the same specs and removed one of 4 gb stick. I started the laptop and tried logging in, but it logs me out immediately while showing:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, ****/**** files, ****/**** blocks
```

message.

Then, I removed 8 gb stick and put back the 4 gb one, but still facing the same issue. Can someone please suggest what the issue could be related to?

Comment: `/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, ... ` is normal, nothing to do with that one ... This sounds like a graphics card issue, did you happen to loosen/move any of the cards on the board while changing the RAM? ... Did you change anything else other than the RAM e.g. a graphics card? ... Did you modify your BIOS stings after changing the RAM? ... Was your BIOS/CMOS data erased or altered during the process e.g. removing the small round battery on the board, touching any jumpers, disconnecting any wires or flipping any tiny switches on it?

Comment: @Raffa, Thanks for the reply.  It doesn't have any dedicated graphics card. I haven't changed anything else other than RAM. I haven't touched anything else. I can login but in a 2-3 seconds I get logged out automatically. Could there be any corruption or something?

Comment: Although rare but file corruption e.g. under the `.config` directory in the user's home can result in that … To confirm, drop to a root shell via the rescue mode and create a new user with `adduser` then reboot and see if you can login normally with the new user … If yes then fix the other user's home directory … Also it’s a good idea to check the last system logged events in the logs.

Comment: I have tried that. For new user also facing the same issue

Comment: Then, please check the logs with e.g. `last` and `journalctl -n 200 --no-pager` and paste the output that you think is relevant to the problem in your question … Also, please tell us about recent software/OS installs/uninstalls/updates that you did if any … Do that by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: Didn't have laptop with me to check the logs. Gave it to a service guy to check. Had to get it formatted as I needed it for some work. Thanks for the suggestions though.